# How to Modify Matplotlib Legend

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

plt.plot(np.arange(0.0,12.0,2.0), 'r-', label='P = increasing')
plt.plot(np.arange(10.0,0.5,-1.8), 'g-', label='P = decreasing')


plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The output is shown in the following figure.,
[image]

But I want to modify the legend so that it can be shown as,
[image]

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
plt.legend(markerfirst = False)
```

From documentation:

> markerfirst : bool
>
> > If *True*, legend marker is placed to the left of the legend label.
> >     If *False*, legend marker is placed to the right of the legend label.
> >     Default is *True*.

Answer (score 1):

This obtains the output you show in the image.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(np.arange(0.0,12.0,2.0), 'r-')
ax.plot(np.arange(10.0,0.5,-1.8), 'g-')

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
labels = ['P = increasing', ' = decreasing']

ax.legend(handles, labels, loc = 'center right', markerfirst = False)
plt.show()
```

[image]